# Is Vuetify's grid compatible with bootstrap grid?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, bootstrap-4, vuetify.js

From the Vuetify docs it says:

> The Vuetify grid is heavily inspired by the [Bootstrap grid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/). It is
>   integrated by using a series of containers, rows, and columns to
>   layout and align content.

Does this mean that if I use bootstrap grid classes in Vuetify project it will work just as if I using Vuetify components (eg. `v-container`, `v-row` and `v-col`)?
In other words, if I copy/paste grid markup from project based on bootstrap to Vuetify project (eg. to `template` in some .vue component), will it *just work*?

Based on [my simple example that I did in this codepen](https://codepen.io/milost1982/pen/PoYQgWE) this indeed seems to be the case, but I'd like to ask just in question.

So this code:

```
<!-- grid layout via Vuetify components -->
<v-container>
  <v-row justify-content-between>
    <v-col cols="2" class="my-col">One of three columns</v-col>
    <v-col cols="5" class="my-col">One of three columns</v-col>
    <v-col cols class="my-col">One of three columns</v-col>
  </v-row>
</v-container>

<!-- grid layout via bootstrap classes  -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-2 my-col">One of three columns</div>
    <div class="col-5 my-col">One of three columns</div>
    <div class="col my-col">One of three columns</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

produces the same layout for both containers.

I can't make conclusion on a single example so I am wondering does this apply in general?

*Note: this question is for Vuetify version 2 and Bootstrap version 4.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is Vuetify Example:

```css
.my-col {
  background: yellowgreen;
  border: 1px red solid;
}
```

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.0.15/dist/vuetify.min.css">

<div class="container my-container">
  <div class="row m-row justify-content-between">
    <div class="col-md-2 my-col">One of three columns</div>
    <div class="col-md-5 my-col">One of three columns</div>
    <div class="col-md-5 my-col">One of three columns</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

this is Bootstrap-4 Example:

```css
.my-col {
  background: yellowgreen;
  border: 1px gray solid;
}
```

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  
<div class="container my-container">
  <div class="row m-row justify-content-between">
    <div class="col-md-2 my-col">One of three columns</div>
    <div class="col-md-5 my-col">One of three columns</div>
    <div class="col-md-5 my-col">One of three columns</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have check for all you ask for:
there are so many differences in Vuetify and Bootstrap-4 because container width and spacing. yes there are all class name are same but its sizing changes at different breakpoints. you can copy paste whole structure of bootstrap template but you have to make changes regarding to spacing and all the things.